# prefix fuzzy query (not using query_string)

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I want to do prefix fuzzy search on single term. 
Basically I want to get same result as if this search request has been sent:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "dala~*"
    }
  },
  "filter": {}
}
```

but without query_string syntax parsing. Search above should match to Dallas term.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631206/lucene-query-bla-match-words-that-start-with-something-fuzzy-how

Comment: "dala~*" query string definitely works for me and Elastc Search documentation states that internal query string is parsed into combination of simplier query conditions. So I am looking if someone can shed some light to which combination of queries it will be parsed.

Comment: After further testing it looks like this query "dala~*" doesn't work as expected, i.e. it splits it on 2 parts "dala~" and "*". And due to last term all documents are matched. But I am still intersted if it is possible to get both partial and fuzzy matching.

Comment: Lucene version you are using??

Comment: I am using latest ElasticSearch

Comment: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/analyzing/AnalyzingQueryParser.html

Answer (score -1):

In ElasticSearch, if you set `fuzzy_prefix_length`, you should be able to specify just the fuzzy tilde and get prefix matching:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "dala~",
      "fuzzy_prefix_length": 3
    }
  },
  "filter": {}
}
```

Similar in spirit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444497/elastic-search-fuzziness-in-query-string)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Fuzzy prefix length just restricts number of terms to be fuzzy matched with pattern.